# Как сбросить биос на ноутбуке ASUS K52F c Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios

Ноутбук **ASUS K52F** *Windows 10*. Раньше все работало но я случано поменял в биосе какую-то настройку типо `EFI` (enable) и после этого все стало не работать. При включении компьютера сразу грузиться винда все `F1` - `F12` и `del` не помогают.

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, возможности вынять и замкнуть контакты в батарейке нет. Пробовал `CMOS De-Animator` не помогло, пробовал вытащить оперативу и включить все ровно не вышло пробовал `Clear CMOS` не пошла на 10.

Если вставить флешку с новой ОС тоже самое биос не реагирует просто проскакивает и грузит винду даже если очень быстро жать `F2` или `del`.

Помогите кто сталкивался подобной проблемой за ранее спасибо.

Comment: Похоже Вы активировали более свежий загрузчик системы [uefi](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface), при загрузки вроде должна быть подсказка, пробовали нажать `esc` или сочетание `shift` + `F2`? [Вот](http://remontka.pro/bios-uefi-windows-10/) как вариант посмотрите, может чем поможет

Answer (score 3):

Обнулить `BIOS` можно использовав утилиту `DEBUG` (входит в состав ОС Windows, предназначенная для оперативного изменения содержимого указанных ячеек памяти.). Для этого нажимаем `ПУСК` --> `ВЫПОЛНИТЬ` (или просто сочетание клавиш `Win+R`).  В строку вводим `cmd`, затем нажимаем кнопку `OK`. Должна открыться командная строка интерпретатора Cmd.exe. В командную строку вводим `debug`. Далее вводим команды:

```
Award BIOS: 
-o 70 17 
-o 71 17 
-q

AMI BIOS: 
-o 70 10 
-o 71 0 
-o 70 11 
-o 71 0 
-q

BIOS Phoenix: 
-o 70 ff 
-o 71 17 
-q
```

В некоторых платах сброс пароля BIOS и загрузка заводских параметров происходит, если при включении держать нажатой клавишу `Ins, Ctrl+Alt+Del+Ins, X+~`.

Comment: win10, нет такого бинаря (раньше, в времена 9x все было конечно)

Comment: debug не является внутренней или внешней командой, нету debug-а

Answer (score 0):

**отключите жесткий диск** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQavHqx05Fo

1. В Windows 10 нажмите и удерживайте клавишу [Shift], одновременно выберите [Перезагрузку] в меню пуск.
2. Нажмите и удерживайте клавишу [F2] во время включения ноутбука.
   возможны варианты: [Del], [F10], [Esc]
3. Вы зашли в настройки BIOS.

либо так:

1. Выключите компьютер Пуск -> Завершить работу (не сон, не закрыть крышку, не нажать клавишу питания!)
2. Нажмите и удерживайте кнопку F2 ,  затем нажмите кнопку включения.
3. Отпустите кнопку F2   и Вы увидите настройки BIOS.

Comment: нет ничего из вышесказанно не помогло делал все как описано но увы

Comment: @user1 обновил ответ, теперь поможет :)

Comment: нет все ровно, все перепробовал ничего не помогло даже пришлось обновить windows думал может появится опция UEFI firmwafe settings не помогло

Answer (score 0):

В последних версиях Windows можно попасть в настройки BIOS через системное меню. Выглядит так:

[image: Вход в EFI]

Если не так, то на ноутбуках ASUS туда же можно попасть [зажимая F2 или ESC при включении](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008829/). Кнопку надо держать нажатой на момент нажатия кнопки включения и до того момента как вы попадете в BIOS.

Comment: нет все ровно, все перепробовал ничего не помогло даже пришлось обновить windows думал может появится опция UEFI firmwafe settings не помогло